# find the same area between 2 images

Tags: c++, c, image

I want to merge 2 images. How can i remove the same area between 2 images?

Can you tell me an algorithm to solve this problem. Thanks.

[image]

Two image are screenshoot image. They have the same width and image 1 always above image 2.

[image: result]

Comment: Can you perform your "merge" by hand, and show us the expected outcome? It's not at all obvious what you mean by "remove the same area between 2 images".

Comment: @meagar My guess is from the two images above, the *merge* would be them joined end-on-end with the portion of the second visible in the first removed.

Comment: Will the two images always have the same width as in your example, with the horizontal alignment always pixel-for-pixel matching as in your example?

Comment: If your images are always, like this one, screenshots, this is not that difficult. OTOH if you are trying to find "same" areas of two different images from the same subject (eg a house), that becomes more challenging... Moreover, if the two pictures have had compression (eg JPG)... that also is more difficult (the pixels won't be exactly the same, at least very likely not to be)

Comment: This description seems to have a lot of ambiguous edge cases.  If image 1 were three pixels `black-red-black` and image 2 were three pixels `red-black-red`. what would you expect to be removed?

Comment: Are the images always the same width?  Are they always merged top-to-bottom?  Is image 1 always above image 2?

Comment: @all: sorry about poor information. Two image are screenshoot image. They have the same width and image 1 always above image 2.

Comment: Is it possibly _image stitching_ what you are looking for? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_stitching

Comment: I tried to do my best to make a *result* image. Please edit and remove if you see a mistake...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When two images have the same width and there is no X-offset at the left side this shouldn't be too difficult.

You should create two vectors of integer and store the CRC of each pixel row in the corresponding vector element. After doing this for both pictures you find the CRC of the first line of the lower image in the first vector. This is the offset in the upper picture. Then you check that all following CRCs from both pictures are identical. If not, you have to look up the next occurrence of the initial CRC in the upper image again.

After checking that the CRCs between both pictures are identical when you apply the offset you can use the bitblit function of your graphics format and build the composite picture.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't come across something similar before but I think the following might work:

- Convert both to grey-scale.
- *Enhance the contrast*, the grey box might become white for example and the text would become *more black*. (This is just to increase the confidence in the next step)
- Apply some threshold, converting the pictures to black and white.

afterwards, you could find the similar areas (and thus the offset of overlap) with a good degree of confidence. To find the similar parts, you could harper's method (which is good but I don't know how reliable it would be without the said filtering), or you could apply some DSP operation(s) like convolution.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If your images are same width and *image 1* is always on top. I don't see how that hard could it be..

Just store the bytes of the last line of *image 1*.

from the first line to the last of the *image 2*, make this test :

If the current line of *image 2* is not equal to the last line of *image 1* -> **continue**
else -> **break** the loop

you have to define a new byte container for your new image :
Just store all the lines of *image 1* + all the lines of *image 2* that start at (the found line + 1).

What would make you sweat here is finding the libraries to manipulate all these  data structures. But after a few linkage and documentation digging, you should be able to easily implement that.